# Export to text or excel from MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, export-to-excel

What I have already : I have controller code churning up some values / calculations and sending them to the View. Right now, I am displaying all results on the view page.

What I am trying to do : Export those results that are displayed on the view to a text or excel file on press of a button "Export"

Using : MVC

Sample code I have

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Calculations()
    {       
            dynamic CalcModel = new ExpandoObject();
            int var1 = //Value calculated here
            int var2 = //Calculation

            CalcModel.Var1= var1;
            CalcModel.Var2= var2;

            return View(CalcModel);

    }
```

View:

```
<table>
   <tr><td>First Value:</td><td><%=Model.Var1%></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Second Value:</td><td><%=Model.Var2%></td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to write these values from the controller to a text file or excel file and let the user save the file. Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

I found a solution (kind of) but need further help:

```
Latest Controller code:

    public ActionResult Calculations()
    {       
            dynamic CalcModel = new ExpandoObject();
            int var1 = //Value calculated here
            int var2 = //Calculation

            CalcModel.Var1= var1;
            CalcModel.Var2= var2;   

            //Export code.

            string csv = "Value1 = " + var1 + "|| Value2 = " + var2; 
            return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", 
            "Report.txt"); 

            //Export code end.

            return View(CalcModel);                  

    }
```

This generates a text file with the values printed in it. But How do I get each value printed in a separate line.. right now all values are printed in one flat line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Envrionment.NewLine should do it:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
//this is probably a loop...
builder.AppendFormat("1,2{0}", Envrionment.NewLine);
builder.AppendFormat("3,4{0}", Envrionment.NewLine);

File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(builder.ToString()), "text/csv", 
        "Report.txt");
```

Edit:
You can try \n as well.

```
string csvText = string.Format("First Value,{0}\nSecond Value,{1}",var1, var2);
File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csvText), "text/csv", 
        "Report.txt");
```

Comment: I am not sure how this works for my sample above.. can you please take a minute and tell me how to do this for my example. Also environment gets a 'not in context' error .. I am using system namespace..

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're going for here.
Are you trying to create a CSV file which is just 1 column of values?

In other words, in your example are var1 and var2 two different records, or two columns of a single record?

Comment: Not a CSV file... in the code I have "Report.txt"..I am just creating a text file with the values printed into it from the controller code... Right now, because of the way I have my code above in OP, it just prints in one flat line. I want var1 to print in first line and var2 to print in a new line under it..

Comment: Your edit suggestion - did not work. I am still getting flat line entries and not two separate lines.

Comment: Okay... it works for csv files. not for text files. Thats fine. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This might help

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/16/asp-net-mvc-tip-2-create-a-custom-action-result-that-returns-microsoft-excel-documents.aspx

Or this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Streaming_Excel_ASP_NET.aspx